# How to store input values from user in json format?

Tags: python, json

I used below code to store student information but I get only one value appearing in the json file.

```
import json

def get_studentdetails():
    data={}
    data['name']=input("Enter Student name")
    data['class']=input("Enter Class")
    data['maths']=input("Enter Marks for Maths")
    data['eng']=input("Enter English Marks")
    data['sci']=input("Enter Science Marks")
    return (data)

out={}
while True:
    quit=input("Enter Y/N to continue")
    if quit.lower()=='n':
        break
    else:
       out['Student_Detail']= get_studentdetails()

    with open('students.json','w') as file:
        json.dump(out,file,indent=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are overwriting your file after each while loop. Do the writing to file outside. Also, You want to store student into list.

```
import json

def get_studentdetails():
    data={}
    data['name']=input("Enter Student name")
    data['class']=input("Enter Class")
    data['maths']=input("Enter Marks for Maths")
    data['eng']=input("Enter English Marks")
    data['sci']=input("Enter Science Marks")
    return (data)
out=[]
while True:
    quit=input("Enter Y/N to continue")
    if quit.lower() == 'n':
        break
    record = get_studentdetails()
    out.append(record)


with open('students.json','w') as file:
    json.dump(out,file,indent=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

for

```
with open('students.json','w') as file:
    json.dump(out,file,indent=2)
```

you need to change the 'w' to 'a'

to append the file